# Using std::remove to delete pointer elements

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do

```
remove(pvec.begin(), pvec.end(), NULL);
```

to remove NULL pointers in the vector (where pvec is `vector<Node*>`)

However, the compiler gives:

"ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer"

How to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++11, use `nullptr`:

```
remove(pvec.begin(), pvec.end(), nullptr);
//                               ^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise, perform an explicit cast to a pointer value. If your `pvec` contains pointers of type `foo*`, write:

```
remove(pvec.begin(), pvec.end(), static_cast<foo*>(NULL));
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```